# how to make header and footer static and move content with boostrap and codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

am working with boostrap and codeigniter and...
how make a footer and header static and only change the content?

```
HEADER

   <div id="content">

   </div>

FOOTER
```

here this
http://i.imgur.com/bXs5IRQ.png

Answer (score 2):

Create `header.php` and place in `/application/views`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    ......
    do you header stuffs here
```

Create `footer.php` and place in `/application/views`

```
        <div class="footer">
        ....
        footer stuff here
        </div>
    </body>
<html>
```

Now in your every view file you can include `header` and `footer` files

```
<?php $this->load->view('header'); ?>

<div id="content">
    ... rest of the dynamic stuffs
</div>

<?php $this->load->view('footer'); ?>
```

Comment: I did not explain well. I am making a system where I have a menu in the header and I have the name of the person who entered the system in the footer. I want to load only what I have in the header and footer once and only when you press on menu button to move only content. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The ci has it's own template, you can use that or write your own output method in the base controller. And I think the bootstrap is a library of CSS and JS. So if you want to use style, you can include bootstrap, but if you want to format the output you should read the ci_user_guide.

Comment: please, could you show me an example?

Comment: i think that gay gave u a good example.